# Execution of curl command in java

Tags: java

We are having a .sh file which executes curl command we need to do the same curl execution of .sh file in java. We are facing problem in replicating the same  behavior of .sh execution in java.

Comment: So what is the exact problem you're having? What have you got so far? What is your actual question?

Answer (score 4):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/yourscript.sh");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to port your shell script to Java, I recommend using an HTTP library made for Java instead of curl, like [Apache Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

However, if you really want to execute your shell script inside a Java program, you can use Darin's suggestion to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/yourscript.sh")`